# magento 2 zoom not working correctly

Tags: magento2, zoom, magnifier

I'm facing a problem with product magnifier on the product detail page. when i hover my mouse over an area in the product image it is more showing other parts of the image and the size doesn't increase. like in this capture

[image]

I tried to modify magnifier properties in the view.xml but it doesn't change anything.
Any help please !!

Comment: add your `view.xml` code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most of this issue is CSS problem.So set css your requirements

For Example :-

```
img, object, video, embed { max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
```

Use bellow css for fix the issue:

```
.magnifier-preview img{ max-height: none; }
```

Any Problem Let me Know.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

On Magento 2.4.5 An change in magnifier.js JS causes this and a change has to be made as follows -

Remove if (data.length > 0) {
since data is an object and the length property is not available on it.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/294a4a2fa94b6ff3458a91bd6b1bea79adc589d9#r103848783